# Set external id Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

So I am new to Laravel and trying to add the project id to project_id to tasks the problem is I put dynamically added text field that's gives a name for each new text field. This error is shown up

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given

**routes**

```
Route::get('todos', [TodoController::class,'index'])->name('todos.index');
Route::get('todos/{id}/show', [TodoController::class,'show'])->name('todos.show');
Route::post('todos/{id}/delete', [TodoController::class,'delete'])->name('todos.destroy');
Route::get('todos/{id}/create', [TodoController::class,'create'])->name('todos.create');
Route::put('todos/store', [TodoController::class,'store'])->name('todos.store');
```

**controller**

```
/**
* Show the form for creating a new resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function create($id,project $project)
{
    $users=User::all();
    $todos=Todo::all();
    return view('todos.create',compact('users','todos','project','id'));
}

/**
* Store a newly created resource in storage.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'moreFields.*.title' => 'required'
    ]);

    foreach ($request->moreFields as $key => $value) {
        Todo::create([
            'title'=>$value,
            'project_id'=>$request->id,
        ]);
    }
    
    return redirect()->route('todos.index')
        ->with('success','task created successfully.');
}
```

**Blade view**

```
<form
  action="{{ route('todos.store',$project->id,$project->id) }}"
  method="POST"
>
  @csrf @method('PUT')

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Name:</strong>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value="{{ $project->name }}"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Name"
          disabled
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Detail:</strong>
        <textarea
          class="form-control"
          style="height: 150px"
          name="detail"
          placeholder="Detail"
          disabled
        >
{{ $project->detail }}</textarea
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamicAddRemove">
      <strong>Tasks:</strong>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="moreFields[0][title]"
            placeholder="Enter Task"
            class="form-control"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" name="add" id="add-btn" class="btn btn-success">
            Add More
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="hidden"
            value="{{ $id }}"
            name="id"
            class="form-control"
          />
          <td></td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;
  $("#add-btn").click(function () {
    ++i;
    $("#dynamicAddRemove").append(
      '<tr><td><input type="text" name="moreFields[' +
        i +
        '][title]" placeholder="Enter title" class="form-control" /></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>'
    );
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".remove-tr", function () {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: For a start. The problem is from this logic ```foreach ($request->moreFields as $key => $value) {
        Todo::create([
            'title'=>$value,
            'project_id'=>$request->id,
        ]);
    }```

Comment: so how i could access the value to store?

Comment: can you show me "dd($request->all())"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for effort but I just discovered the problem
in the controller I just added

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'moreFields.*.title' => 'required'
    ]);

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($request->moreFields as $key => $value) {
        Todo::create([
            'title' => $request->moreFields[$i]['title'],
            'project_id' => $request->id,
        ]);
        $i++;
    }

    return redirect()
        ->route('todos.index')
        ->with('success', 'task created successfully.');
}
```

Comment: You don't need `$i = 0;` or `$i++;` that is already available via `$key`, but so is `$value`: `foreach ($request->moreFields as $key => $value) { Todo::create(['title' => $value['title'], 'project_id' => $request->id]); }` (or similar)

Comment: Told ya it was from that logic.  Glad to know that you fixed it!